# Python Django Template: Iterate Through List

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Technically it should iterate from 0 to rangeLength outputting the user name of the c[i][0].from_user...but from looking at example online, they seem to replace the brackets with dot notation. I have the following code:

```
<div id="right_pod">
{%for i in rangeLength%}
    <div class="user_pod" >
        {{c.i.0.from_user}}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

This currently outputs nothing :( If I replace "i" with 0...{{c.0.0.from_user}}...it will output something.. (the first user 10 times)

Comment: Please provide the structure of `c`.  Otherwise this is hard to interpret.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Do you need `i` to be an index? If not, see if the following code does what you're after:

```
<div id="right_pod">
{% for i in c %}
    <div class="user_pod">
        {{ i.0.from_user }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ideally I need i to be an index so I can limit the amount of users to loop over. Should I be doing this in the Controller before passing c to the template?

Comment: +1 for doing this in the controller layer; the view shouldn't contain business logic like that.

Comment: -1 for *necessarily* doing this is the controller. Suppose you need the full list in other parts of the page. It's wasteful to pass in the full list *and* the truncated list. In such a case you should just pass the full list and use the slice filter suggested by @sotangochips.

Answer (score 15):

Please read the entire [documentation on the template language's for loops](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for). First of all, that iteration (like in Python) is over objects, not indexes. Secondly, that within any for loop there is a forloop variable with two fields you'll be interested in:

```
Variable            Description
forloop.counter     The current iteration of the loop (1-indexed)
forloop.counter0    The current iteration of the loop (0-indexed)
```

Answer (score 9):

You should use the slice template filter to achieve what you want:

Iterate over the object (c in this case) like so:

```
{% for c in objects|slice:":30" %}
```

This would make sure that you only iterate over the first 30 objects.

Also, you can use the forloop.counter object to keep track of which loop iteration you're on.